# No internet access when I'm connect to my company's VPN

Tags: internet, networking, vpn, pptp, network-manager

I googled my problem and I've read some questions in Ask Ubuntu, but I didn't solve my problem.

I connect to a PPTP VPN server and it works well, but when I'm connected to that VPN I don't have Internet access but private network access.

If I check "Use this connection only for resources on its network", I have Internet access, but this way I haven't access to my company's private network.

What's the problem? Help, please.

Answer (score 1):

First, look at the company's policy on VPN connections. What you're trying to do may be disallowed. If you have a VPN to the company, and use the internet to get subverted by a Black Hat, then the Black Hat has a VPN to the company with your identity. If you access the internet through the VPN and whatever else the company requires, if you get subverted, they bear some responsibility.

Take a look at the route you have when connected and not connected to the VPN, with `netstat -rn`. Read `man route`. Be aware - when you fiddle with routes, you can end up with nowhere to send packets, if you're not careful.

Comment: All my coworkers (they are using Windows) can connect to company's VPN and they have internet access with their own connection.

Comment: With their own connections? Really not secure - who set it up?

Comment: By "Really not secure" I mean: What if a BlackHat subverts a Windows computer via its Internet access? Then the BlackHat has the same VPN access to the company that the Windows user has, and it will all come from the Windows users' account!

Comment: Just to add comment to comment.  I work for a Fortune 300 company and when I connect to VPN I still have my own regular internet access as well.  This being said, because my corporate network doesn't allow for things such as Facebook, YouTube, that nature but I can still access them while connected to VPN.  I'm not a network guy, hate it actually, but it does seem pretty insecure this way >.>

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to a VPN, by default NM routes all traffic through the VPN. This means, if you try to access the internet it happens through your company's network. If your company does not allow this (or requires some special configuration), Internet access fails.

If you check "Use this connection only for resources on its network", I believe, NM tries to guess which network can be reached through the VPN and routes everything else to the internet as without the VPN. Now, it seems in your case, this guess is to conservative, giving you only access to a subset of your company's network.

There's no way to resolve this without knowing the topology of your company's network.

Comment: If it's worth, my private network IP is 192.168.1.* and my company's private network IP is 192.168.2.*. NM may be confused with this range of IPs.

Comment: @lago, this isn't enough information to sort out the issue. May I suggest, you talk to your IT department. Or maybe, figure out, which routes are set up by the Windows VPN client. The minimum information, you need, is the IP address of a server on your corporate network, which you want to access through the VPN. (And pray it does not happen to be in 192.168.1/24.)

Comment: See RFC 1918 http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1918.txt both those address ranges are "non-routable" and for local use only. Your corp must have a public IP address (not in the
`
    10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
    172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
    192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)`

ranges

Comment: @Jan all what I have is a public IP of my corporate's VPN (public IP address of the server) and two private DNS IP address of my corporate network.